# How to truly automate a powershell script without scheduler

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

My script basically runs on specific times during a day. Accesses the server and downloads data.

So far I have tried playing around with start-sleep command and timespan command but I am new to this.

```
start-sleep ((get-date "03:04 pm") - (get-date)).TotalSeconds; 
$filename = (get-date -format "hh_mm_dd_MM_yyyy") + "AU" + ".csv"
$xacontroller = "abc.contoso.com"
$xasessions = Get-BrokerSession -AdminAddress $xacontroller - 
MaxRecordCount 100000 | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\Data\$filename"


start-sleep ((get-date "03:06 pm") - (get-date)).TotalSeconds;
$filename = (get-date -format "hh_mm_dd_MM_yyyy") + "SG" + ".csv"
$xacontroller = "def.contoso.com"
$xasessions = Get-BrokerSession -AdminAddress $xacontroller - 
MaxRecordCount 100000 | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\Data\$filename"
```

Logic : sleep till 3:04 PM and run the first block. sleep till 3:06 PM and run the second block.

What I am trying to achieve : Sleep after 3:06 PM till next day 3:04 PM

Expectation : This script needs to run everyday automatically without using task scheduler. I am using powershell 3.

Any ideas are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Check out jobs - > https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_jobs?view=powershell-6

Comment: What's the reason Task Scheduler isn't used? Its very purpose is to schedule runs at specific times, so not using it sounds weird.

Comment: powershell is VERY BAD at running for long periods of time. [*grin*] really quite bad in that it sometimes will crash, hang, or just vanish if left running for "long enuf". it is simply not designed for what you are describing. so ... use what IS designed for such - task scheduler is one such thing.

Comment: A reason I looked for this solution: I am looking for a secure method to run a task automatically while not logged in. Storing Password, not so much a good idea.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Often this is because GC doesn't occur when you would think due to how PowerShell executes code. If you understand how garbage collection works though you can suggest when it runs in your script and you can create the condition (such as introducing a sufficient sleep) for GC to occur at appropriate times. This won't always fix problems with long running scripts, but can help when you do have a "daemonized" script you want to run as a long running process/service.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest - yep, there are ways around it ... but they all have gotchas. it appears to be better to bite the bullet and switch to using c# when you find that you need ling-running code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run the script at specific time, you should have something looking for this time to come (you can call it event handler).

In WMI for example, event handler is a something waiting for specific event to happen (e.g: startup, when external volume is plugged...)

In task scheduler, the events can be system startup, user login, daily at specific time (which is what you want)...

I don't think it is a good practice to keep your powershell script running all the day to perform single task at specific time, instead task scheduler is available.

Save your script in a location and use the following script to register new scheduled task at specific time to run it.

```
$ScriptPath = "$home\Desktop\script.ps1"
$Trigger= New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -At 03:04pm
$Action= New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "PowerShell.exe" -Argument "-executionpolicy bypass -noprofile -file $ScriptPath" 
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "MyTask" -Trigger $Trigger -User $env:username -Action $Action
```